# Left logo, right align horizontal nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage with a horizontally aligned navigation bar menu on the right and for some reason nothing I'm trying is seeming to work? If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great, thanks in advance. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ArtStore</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head><body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo.png" width="125px">
        </div><nav class="topnav">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#products">Products</a>
        <a href="#login">Login</a>
          <a href="#cart">Cart</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.navbar{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.topnav{
  flex:1;
  text-align: right;
}

.topnav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:20;
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

All it's showing is the logo on the left with the text all horizontally laid out underneath it, as well as underlined :/

Comment: The code you provided seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/gu9koqm8/  Maybe you have some other CSS somewhere.

Comment: Omg. I'd linked the wrong Css file. Wowww

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works - I'd linked the wrong CSS file. Wow lol